# Can I modify Kafka compatibility from FULL_TRANSITIVE to FORWARD_TRANSITIVE

Tags: apache-kafka, compatibility, confluent-schema-registry

Is it possible to change the schema registry compatibility setting from FULL_TRANSITIVE to FORWARD_TRANSITIVE in production?

I gone through below docs but it does not answer my question.
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/schema-evolution.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why "production" matters.

It's a valid config value, so yes you are able to modify it to that

Obviously you'll lose backwards compatibility guarantee, but that really depends on your specific usage of schemas. For example, if you're not archiving data in HDFS, S3, etc, or never have consumers reading older data from the topic, then you may not need it